# How to create Item in right context menu for all extensions except .zip?

Tags: registry

I need to create Item in right context menu for all files except .zip

I thought that I'm able to use something like this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*
```

and exclude only .zip somehow

is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set context menu accorging to different dependencies by customizing a Shortcut Menu Using Dynamic Verbs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee453696(VS.85).aspx